# Apache couldn't be started because port 8888 is in use by some other software

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosts, mamp

I am having an issue starting up MAMP, when I attemp it, I get this error message:

Apache couldn't be started because port 8888 is in use by some other software

I have been trying for the last 2 days. 
I have tried changing ports, I have tried deleting the httpd.pid and MySQL.pid files and I have tried reinstalling MAMP all together with no luck.

As it is right now I have no access to my website, I am trying to get on my myphp.admin to move my wordpress database to a new host (was using a local host)

If anyone knows how I can fix my issue with MAMP or how I could go about moving my database without access to myphp.admin (if that's even possible) that would be fantastic, I am running out of options here.

Comment: Maybe Tomcat or Skype?

Comment: This issue popped up occasionally on older versions of MAMP but is a non-issue (at least in my experience) on newer versions. The solution I had was simply  to reboot my Mac. The next solution would be to rename the installed MAMP  directory, reinstall the exact same version of  MAMP and then manually move over the `db/` and `htdocs/` directory from the old install to the new one. Toss out the old MAMP directory, start MAMP again and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about MAMP, but when I see that something else is using a port that I want to use, I can find out which process it is by doing `netstat -napl | grep <portno>` as root. This will list the process that is listening on that port. You can then use that information to figure out what is getting in the way.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I do a "netstat -Napl | grep" ??? I have no idea what that is. :/

Comment: First, you open a root shell on your server. Then you type the command line "netstat -napl | grep 8888" This will show you the name and process ID of the process that is using that port number.

Comment: All it says when I enter that is:

Comment: Unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Comment: It sounds like your version of netstat has a different "-p" option than the one I'm used to. I presume MacOS X? The goal of the command is to find the actual program binding to port 8888, which prevents Apache from also binding to that port, because the error means "something else already uses port 8888." That "something else" might be another copy of Apache, for all I know -- you have to investigate that using system administration methods.

Comment: Use `lsof -nP -i:8888 | grep LISTEN` at the root shell. Note you MUST be root to get output.